# jQuery append doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
for ( j = 0; j < albums[0].imagesNumber; j++ ) {
    k = albums[0].imagesNumber * 170;
    $('.body-album-expanded-inner').css({ width: k + 'px' });
    document.getElementsByClassName('body-album-expanded-inner')[0].
    appendChild(albumsImages[0][j]);
}
```

where `albumsImages` contains some `images` and `albums[].imagesNumber` just tells me how many images exists in an `album`. When I use javascript's appendChild everything works fine, but when I use jQuery's append like this:

```
$('.body-album-expanded-inner')[0].
    append(albumsImages[0][j]);
```

it gives me this error:

`TypeError: $(...)[0].append is not a function`

Comment: Because it should be `$('.body-album-expanded-inner').append(albumsImages[0][j]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you're using an *indexer* which converts into a native DOM element. Use `eq(0)` or `first()`

```
$('.body-album-expanded-inner').eq(j). // or simply first()
    append(albumsImages[0][j]);
```

Another option is to wrap it again with jQuery but that's an over kill. Any way

```
$($('.body-album-expanded-inner')[j]). //now it's jQuery since its wrapped inside $()
    append(albumsImages[0][j]);
```

If it's the single element out there, then you don't need anything, then just use `append`

`jQuery` accepts a native DOM element and gives out `jQuery` object which has methods such as `append`, but not `appendChild`, similarly native elements won't have `jQuery` specific methods such as `append` but only `appendChild`.

Comment: I cant understand why `$('.body-album-expanded-inner')[0]` is different from `$($('.body-album-expanded-inner')[0])`

Comment: @dfsq I thought he wanted only the first one in the collection

Comment: No the [0] its just and example. In my full code I use for loop. So it's [i]

Comment: @Dim_Ch jQuery accepts a native DOM element and gives out jQuery element which has methods such as `append`, but not `appendChild`, similarly native elements won't have jQuery specific methods such as `append` but only `appendChild`

Comment: So, if I got it right the `$('.body-album-expanded-inner')[i].append()` doesn't work because `$('.body-album-expanded-inner')[i]` is DOM element but append() function works for jQuery objects ?

Comment: It seems so simple now. Thanks

Comment: @Dim_Ch glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Some more explanations below.

This is DOM element object

```
document.getElementsByClassName('body-album-expanded-inner')[0]
```

It has bunch of methods defined for DOM elements, like `appendChild`, `removeChild`, etc.

Then there is jQuery function constructor. Instance of jQuery is not a DOM element, it's just some custom object which happens to work with DOM elements, wrapping them. These jQuery objects have many useful methods defined on jQuery function prototype `jQuery.fn.prototype`. For example `append`, `text`, `after`, and many more.

jQuery instance object is an array-like collection, meaning that you can access individual DOM elements as if jQuery object was an array. So

```
$('.body-album-expanded-inner')[0]
```

is again DOM element (while `$('.body-album-expanded-inner')` is jQuery object) which of course don't have jQuery methods.

In order to be able to use jQuery methods one should use `jQuery` instance for this. Wrapping DOM element or NodeList collection of DOM elements into `$()` constructs new jQuery instance, which has all necessary methods.